# What does "scientific report" mean?

Tags: job-search, terminology

An Australian bioinformatics job ad talks about writing "scientific reports" in the selection criteria.

Wikipedia has an article on [Technical reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_report), which it says are also called scientific reports, but that definition, of basically grey literature, doesn't seem plausible.

Does it have any other meanings, such as a hypernym of scientific papers, conference talks, and conference posters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would construe "scientific report" here to encompass all forms of scientific publication and communication, including peer-reviewed papers as well as possibly internal technical reports. Remember that a technical report is just something that hasn't gone through peer review.

The exception would be if this were for a corporate position, where publication may be more difficult. In such cases, one would expect "grey literature" to be the primary "publication" mode.